# PM2 environment variables not read

Tags: pm2

I try to use environment variables for a nodejs app running with PM2. On local machine I have a .env file with environment variables and I can read them lik for instance

```
const OAUTH_EMAIL = process.env.OAUTH_EMAIL || '' as string;
```

after using command dotenv.config();

On the server, with PM2 I have a ecosystem.config.js file for that purpose, like

```
module.exports = {
    apps : [
        {
          name: "file-uploader",
          script: "./server.js",
          watch: true,
          env: {
            "OAUTH_EMAIL": "some@email.com"
          }
        }
    ]
  }
```

and that is not being read in the application (console.log of the environment variable process.env.OAUTH_EMAIL shows value undefined)

As far as I understand from the [PM2 docs](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/environment/) I just need to create a file with that name and put it in the root of the project and then it would automatically be read by PM2 on start of the app. But apparently that doesn't work (I stopped the app completely with command pm2 stop appname and started it).

Should I import this file in my app? Should I run / start that ecosystem.config.js file with PM2 just like I run the app? Or should I start the ecosystem file instead of starting the app? Something else I'm missing to make it possible to work with environment variables with PM2 (on Ubuntu server / NodeJS site running under Cloudpanel)?

Comment: Could you please update the details with which `Nodejs server library` you are using to create the server application? Or I suggest you follow the quick-start https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start

Comment: I found that I actually had to start the config-file instead of starting the app, which is described in the pm2 quick-start document. Do you know if I can leave the existing cronjob command ```@reboot pm2 resurrect &> /dev/null``` unchanged (following setup indtructions on https://www.cloudpanel.io/docs/v2/nodejs/deployment/pm2/?ygp3qhdcuoasslwcdf4yjye3bq=uuntqhkcqsgdbol4dbpvkzpjrm)?
I'm running node 20 LTS or didn't you mean that?

Comment: I mean to say, did you use any library(Express, Koa, etc.) Even if you are using core NodeJs without any library, you have to use the PM2 setup file with your app. I don't understand what you mean to say about corn job. Could you please clarify, also do you want me to share with you a full project setup for PM2?

Comment: I was using only dotenv, nodemailer and googleapis, no express. I have other apps (with express) running without a setup file (not using env variables). To make them run and automatically start on server reboot i did 1. pm2 start npm --name $app-name -- start, 2. pm2 save, 3. add a cron job, like: echo $PATH -> crontab -e ->  PATH=$PASTE_THE_OUTPUT_OF_$PATH
@reboot pm2 resurrect &> /dev/null. Now I needed to use environment variables. Now I understand that I have to start the config file and I think I have the automatic start after reboot now also working with the pm2 startup script.

Comment: Well I thought it was working: the app starts after reboot after running the script created with pm2 startup, but now it says 'cannot find name process' trying to read the environment variables, like process.env.PORT. I have to say I cannot use sudo for current user (doesn't work also after adding user to sudo group) so I logged in as root and then ran that script. Didn't run pm2 save after that since pm2 isn't installed for root-user. Do you know how to fix that? BTW I have added express library in the meantime to this app.

Comment: If I use pm2 start npm --name $app-name -- start to start the app then the server starts running (Node.je process) but when running command pm2 start ecosystem.config.js no process starts running (although pm2 status of the app is online). Should I add something to the ecosystem file to make that happen?

Comment: Using pm2 log I found that the server was actually running so i tested it with a curl script and it is actually running fine now...